# Unhandled exception to double size of array.

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

void growArray(double* array, int size)
{
    double* stackArray = 0;
    double*  newArray = &array[size * 2];

    for (int i = 0; i < size * 2; i++)
    {
        if (i < size)
        {
            newArray[i] = stackArray[i];
        }
        else
        {
            newArray[i] = 0;
        }
    }
    stackArray = newArray;
    size *= 2;

    delete[] array;
}



int main()
{
    double* myArray = new double[3];
    for (int i = 0; i<3; i++)
        myArray[i] = (i + 1) * 2;

    growArray(myArray, 3);

    for (int i = 0; i<6; i++)
        cout << myArray[i] << endl;

    delete[]myArray;

    return 0;
}
```

The error occurs on this line "newArray[i] = stackArray[i];" - and it states "Unhandled exception at 0x00A01993 in Project8.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000." What is causing this? Thanks!

Comment: `&array[size * 2]` doesn't "grow" the "array", it just returns an out-of-bounds pointer.

Comment: You also don't return the "new" pointer anywhere, perhaps you need to look up *references* and passing arguments by reference?

Comment: arrays are pointers basically theres no need to dereference it

Comment: Adding to the list of problems. `stackArray` is initialized to null, and never set to anything else, so `stackArray[i]` is wrong as well. From what I see that variable is pointless for the purposes of this code.

Comment: Lastly, I assume this is an exercise to learn how to use pointer, or else using [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) would be a better option.

Comment: Your function deletes the array then main tries to access the deleted space